# Best way to make application available for distribution

Tags: c#, deployment, ftp, software-distribution

I've developed a software application and have reached the point where I need to find an easier way to supply updates to users.  I've currently created an "Installer" application - which is just a simple C# application that connects to an FTP server, supplies credentials, brings down the parts of the application and assembles it.  This installer is called by the main application if the user chooses to update their version of the application.  (The first step of the installer is to kill the main application process, thereby allowing the files to be overwritten.)
To determine if a new version is available, the application reads a simple text file that is hosted on my website (i.e. www.mydomain.com/versionFile.txt) .  This text file basically contains the latest version number, which the main application uses to compare to its version.

It all works, but it can be cumbersome if a user is on a site that does not allow FTP access (which is often.)

So as not to be subjective, here is my specific question: 
Is there a secure way to make application files available on a website for download?
By secure, I mean the C# Installer application needs to supply the correct credentials before being able to download the application files to the users PC.

I've seen how one developer distributes his application via a dropbox public folder, but this is open to everyone, which I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks in advance.

Steve

Comment: Plenty of cloud apps will facilitate this for you...Amazon S3, Azure Blobs, etc, and there are lots of examples as well as Nuget packages for their respective SDKs.  You could also restrict access to the files on your own server and facilitate authentication between the client and the update service and deliver them via authenticated http.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP (or even better HTTPS if you care about unauthorized third parties sniffing passwords) will do, will be block much less often, and you can fetch file as simply as with FTP (or even easier). You also have password protection as with FTP, called [basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)